# Can I have multiple log4net configuration files?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Can I have multiple [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) [configurations](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for the same program?  Functionality similar to Spring's `<import>` element would be optimal.  The idea here would to have multiple programs that have their own log4net configuration, as well as sharing a central log4net configuration file containing a shared error log (so that definition isn't repeated).  Alternatively is this functionality possible with [.NET Common Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/)?

---

**Related:** [log4net - configure using multiple configuration files](http://log4net%20-%20configure%20using%20multiple%20configuration%20files)

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by using named repositories i think

```
log4net.LogManager.CreateRepository(repositoryName)
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repositoryName, configFile)
```

then by using

```
LogManager.GetLogger(repositoryName,loggerName)
```

you can get the corresponding logger.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem.  I don't want multiple sets of configuration, I want one set of configuration which happens to be in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Not out-of-the-box. You must implement yourself the merging of different config files into a single XmlNode and pass this to log4net XmlConfiguratot.

An example is to be found here: http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/using-multiple-configuration-files-with-log4net